# insert into select query-multipart identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

this query returns multipart identifier could not be bound for

```
table2.AId and  table1.LId = table2.LId
```

the query is

```
insert into table1(col1)
select col2 from table2
where table1.AId = table2.AId and  table1.LId = table2.LId;
```

your help is highly appreciated

Comment: What your query supposed to do?

Comment: To use table1 columns in your select query, you have to JOIN the table1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include all tables in the `SELECT` in the `FROM` clause.  So, this is syntactically correct:

```
insert into table1(col1)
    select t2.col2
    from table2 t2 join
         table1 t1
         on t1.AId = t2.AId and t1.LId = t2.LId;
```

However, you probably intend `UPDATE`:

```
update t1
    set col1 = t2.col2
    from table1 t1 join
         table2 t2             
         on t1.AId = t2.AId and t1.LId = t2.LId;
```

This modifies the rows in `t1`.  The version with `insert` will insert new rows with new values only in one column.

Comment: too fast for me :-)

Comment: I missed join. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Your select query does not "know" the table in the insert into part, so you should use a join:

```
insert into table1(col1)
select col2 
from table2
inner join table1 on table1.AId = table2.AId and  table1.LId = table2.LId;
```

However, I suspect you are looking for update rather then insert:

```
update t1
set col1 = t2.col2 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.AId = t2.AId and  t1.LId = t2.LId;
```

Comment: I missed join. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Missing `join` condition

```
insert into table1(col1)
    select t2.col2
    from table2 t2 join
         table1 t1
         on t1.AId = t2.AId and t1.LId = t2.LId;
```

Comment: I missed join. Thank You